# Is it possible to add a parameter to a function with a decorator in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

So I tried to write a decorator function to secure the access to a function with a "password string" `auth`. The decorator function looks like this:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if "auth" in kwargs.keys():
            if kwargs["auth"] == "12345":
                func(*args, **kwargs)
                return
        print("Not authorized.")

    return wrapper
```

The definition of the example function I want to secure looks like this:

```
@decorator
def add(list, elem, auth):
    list.append(elem)
```

In my main code, I am calling `add()` like this:

```
def main():
    lst = [3,5]
    add(lst, 2, auth="12345")
    print(lst)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My goal is to be able to do this, without explicitly mentioning `auth` in `add()`'s definition, so I can just do this:

```
@decorator
def add(list, elem):
    list.append(elem)
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Try it and find out...

Comment: How secure is it supposed to end up being?

Comment: @MattDMo Well I don't know how, this is why I am asking. Just removing ```auth``` from ```add()```'s argument list is obviously not working, but I thought there may be another solution.

Comment: @lucidbrot It is just practice, not a real security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get what you want with:

```
if kwargs.pop("auth", None) == "12345":
```

You need to remove the `"auth"` argument since you are using it and don't want to pass it to the child.

You should also replace

```
func(*args, **kwargs)
return
```

with

```
return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

in case you happen to be calling a function that returns a value.